# Is it possible to have a non-zero solution for $v$ in $(A-\lambda I)v=0$if $\det(A-\lambda I) \neq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

Suppose I have an equation: \begin{equation}(A-\lambda I){\textbf v}={\textbf0} \end{equation}
The characteristic equation for eigenvalue\vector is that $\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$ and it this is met then we have eigenvalues and eigenvectors.
But suppose that we have $\det(A-\lambda I) \neq 0$, this means that we have $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ which means \begin{equation}(A-\lambda I)^{-1}(A-\lambda I) {\textbf v}=(A-\lambda I)^{-1}{\textbf0} \end{equation}
thus\begin{equation} {\textbf v}={\textbf0} \end{equation}

My question is:

> Can have $\det(A-\lambda I) \neq 0$ and a vector ${\textbf v}$ such that ${\textbf v}\neq{\textbf0}$ for $(A-\lambda I){\textbf v}={\textbf0}$ or is it only possible to have ${\textbf v}={\textbf0}$ ?

Comment: $A-\lambda I$ is invertible, so the answer is NO.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply

Comment: This is an iff condition . You may try showing that $(A-\lambda.I)v = 0$ has a solution iff $\det(A-\lambda.I)=0$

Comment: You might want to also check out Cramer's Rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know that a square matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if $\det A \ne 0$?

Since $\det(A-\lambda I)\ne 0$, $B:= (A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ exists. Consider $(A-\lambda I)v = 0$. Multiplying by $B$ on both sides, we have $B(A-\lambda I)v = 0 \implies v = 0$ as $B(A-\lambda I) = I$ by choice of $B$. Therefore, if $\det(A-\lambda I) \ne 0$,  $(A-\lambda I) v = 0$ if and only if $v = 0$.

To summarize, $(A-\lambda I) v = 0$ has no solution except $v = 0$.